# How to assign Roles to new user in Flask - TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I want to assign roles to users after they've signed up in Flask (using flask.ext.user).

I define UserRoles and Roles as per: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/roles_required_app.html#create-roles-required-app-py

But when I try to auto-add a role after a user register:

```
@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def _after_reg_hook(sender, user, **extra):
    new_role = UserRoles(user.id,1)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Unfortunately the doco example (linked above) doesn't give a practical way of adding roles after registration, so not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy provides a default constructor which assigns *named* arguments to corresponding attributes.  You passed in *positional* arguments.

```
UserRoles(user_id=user.id, role_id=1)
```

---

However, you shouldn't be instantiating an association directly, and in fact the example is somewhat misleading as there's no reason to define a full model for the association in this case, since you're not storing any additional data with the association.

Instead, assign a `Role` directly to the `roles` collection on `User` (or the `users` collection on `Role`).  Note that this will not check when creating duplicate roles, you should follow the [unique object](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject) recipe for that.